# How do I install Ubuntu on a new build?

Tags: installation

I've just completed a new build and want to install Ubuntu.  I can download from another W7 pc.  Can I boot from the memory stick?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by completing a new build?

Comment: I think new build = new PC

Comment: Oh alright I think zuberuber's answer is correct then

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it is a new PC.  Thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can install Ubuntu on flash drive using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).